# Applying the continuity corrections removes equivalence between p-value condition and test statistic condition?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Assume the population follows $Poi(\lambda)$ distribution, I want to test $H_0: \lambda \geq \lambda_0$ versus $H_1:\lambda<\lambda_0$. The variable we usually use in this type of test is $$\frac{\bar X - \lambda}{\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{1/2}}\sim^aN(0,1).$$

I would compute the p-value with the correction as such:

$$\text{p-value}\approx P\left(N(0,1) \leq \frac{\bar x - \lambda_0 + \frac{1}{2n}}{\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{n}\right)^{1/2}}\right)$$

This computation, we get it from $P(\sum X_i\leq\sum x_i)=P(\sum X_i\leq\sum x_i+1/2)$ and then subtracting and dividing by the obvious terms.

However, I think I get a bit confused when computing the rejection region. For dimension $\alpha$, the rejection region would be usually obtained from $\alpha=P(\sum X_i < c|H_0)$, where $c$ is a constant to be determined. From here we would proceed as $P(\sum X_i < c-1/2|H_0)$ giving $\alpha=P\left(\frac{\bar X - \lambda_0}{\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{n}\right)^{1/2}}\leq \frac{\bar x - \lambda_0-\frac{1}{2n}}{\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{n}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\approx P(N(0,1)\leq q_{\alpha})$

But now, it seems that the continuity correction  has not changed anything, since I still get the same condition ($z_0<q_{\alpha}$) with or without... (**although we get different constants $c$'s**).

Thus,

- Without continuity correction: $z_0<q_{\alpha}$ is equivalent to the uncorrected p-value$<\alpha$.
- With continuity correction: we still have $z_0<q_{\alpha}$ which is equivalent to the uncorrected p-value$<\alpha$, however it may no longer be equivalent to corrected p-value$<\alpha$, because when computing with the corrected p-value I may get a bigger value (adding a $1/(2n)$ term) than $\alpha$, in which case I wouldn't reject, but I could still get $z_0<q_{\alpha}$  telling me to reject...

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: To make it clear, my problem is **not** not realising we get different constants $c$'s. I do realise it, and maybe should have said that in a more explicit way. The whole problem resides on the fact that almost all statistical programmes when doing tests besides doing the p-value, they also show the test-statistic $Z_0$. However, as I show above the p-value no longer seems equivalent to the test-statistic condition. The p-value will still be equivalent to the condition with the c constants (corrected or not).

Comment: I've also posted in MathSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071088/how-to-apply-the-continuity-corrections-to-hypothesis-testing

Comment: If you are determined to use a normal approximation, then you have applied the continuity correction correctly.  More generally, if $X$ takes integer values, but is approximately normal, then to approximate $P(X \le k)$ it's best to get the normal equivalent of $P(X \le k + .5).$ // You want to include $P(X = k)$ into your answer and  to get the normal aprx to that, you need to consider $P(k-.5 < X \le k+.5)$ for best results. // By contrast, if you're approximating $P(X < k) = P(X \le k-1)$ by normal, then best to start with $P(X \le k - ,5).$

Comment: @BruceET Hi, thanks for your comment. And in your opinion, if the the p-value tells me to not reject, and the critical value condition tells me to reject, which one would you choose?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title of your question should be NO. If you are careful, you should never have to make the choice your comment poses! Whether you use the critical value or the P-value, they should both give you the same decision whether to Reject. // See Addendum to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're testing $H_0: \lambda \le 5$ against $H_a: \lambda_X < 5)$ with $n = 10$ random observations $X_i$ from the Poisson population. Let $T = \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i,$
where $T\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_T = n\lambda_X = 50),$ according to $H_0.$

You want to reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ at the 5% level for small values of $T.$
In particular, you want to reject when $T \le c,$ where the the *critical value* $c$ is chosen so that $P(T \le c\,|\,\lambda_T = 50) \le 0.05,$ but as near to $0.05,$ being below $0.05.$ In R, we find that $P(T \le 38\,|\,\lambda_T=50) = 0.474,$ so you can
test at level $\alpha = 4.74\%,$ but not exactly at $\alpha = 5\%.$

```
qpois(.05, 50)
[1] 39
ppois(38, 50)
[1] 0.04737066
```

If you're using a normal approximation in R, you might approximate $c$ as $c^\prime = 28.37$ as below, where $T \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sqrt{50}).$

```
qnorm(.05, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 38.36913
pnorm(38.37, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.05001271
```

This gives the ***illustion*** of a test at exactly the 5% level, but of course the integer count $T$ couldn't be exactly 38.37.

Now, suppose your ten observations give you $T = 35$ or $\bar X = 35/10 = 3.5.$
Then the exact P-value is $P(T \le 35 \,|\, \lambda_T = 50) = 0.0162 < 0.05 = 5\%,$
and you reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

```
ppois(35, 50)
[1] 0.01621388
```

In terms of $T,$ your method using a normal approximation, standardizing, and referring to printed
normal CDF tables would go as follows (using continuity correction):

$$P(T \le 35) = P(T \le 35.5) = 
P\left(\frac{T-\lambda_T}{\sqrt{\lambda_T}} \le \frac{35.5-50}{7.0711}\right)\\
\approx P(Z \le -2.05) = 0.0202,$$

from normal CDF tables, or R (as below). For practical purposes of deciding whether
to reject $H_0$ at the 5% level, this is nearly the same as the exact Poisson P-value.

```
pnorm(-2.05)
[1] 0.02018222
```

Alternatively, in terms of $\bar X,$ you might find the P-value, using your equation, as follows:

$$P\left(Z < \frac{\bar X - \lambda_x + 1/2n}{\sqrt{\lambda_x/n}} 
= \frac{3.5 - 5 + 1/20}{\sqrt{5/10}} = -2.05\right) = 0.0202,$$

as before.

```
(3.5 - 5 + 1/20)/sqrt(5/10)
[1] -2.05061
```

The P-value is the probability in the lower tail to the left of the
vertical dotted line.

[image]

R oode for figure:

```
t = 0:80;  PDF = dpois(t, 50)
hdr = "POIS(50) with Density of NORM(50, 7.0711)"
plot(t, PDF, type="h", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 35.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, 50, sqrt(50)), add=T, col="orange")
```

---

**Addendum:**  Without saying so explicitly, we have
been talking about three similar, but not
identical tests. It is important not to mix them:

**(1) Exact Poisson test.** Critical value is $c = 38,$
so your reject at level $\alpha = P(T \le 38) = 0.0474.$

```
ppois(38, 50)
[1] 0.04737066
```

If you observe $T = 35,$ then Reject $H_0$ because $35 \le 38.$ Alternatively, if you want to use a
P-value, it is $P(T \le 35) = 0.0162,$ and Reject
because $0.0152 < 0.0474.$

```
ppois(35, 50)
[1] 0.01621388
```

**(2) Normal approximation with no continuity correction.** What is the critical value?

```
qnorm(.05, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 38.36913
```

You could say it's a test at 5% level with
critical value $c = 38.3691.$ But that can't
be true because $T$ takes integer values.
So the real critical value has to be $c = 38$
at level $\alpha = 0.0448.$

```
pnorm(38, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.04484301
```

Then if you observe $T =35,$ then you reject $H_0$ because $35 \le 38.$ Or you find the P-value $0.0169$ and you reject because $0.169 < 0.558.$

```
pnorm(35, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.01694743
```

**(3)  Normal approximation with continuity correction** (throughout).

As before, you observe that $38.3691$ cuts
5% from the lower tail of the approximating normal distribution. But again $T$ is an integer and
so you decide $c = 38.$ Then the true level of the test (with continuity correction) is
$\alpha = P(T \le 38) = P(T < 38.5) = 0.0519 > 0.05.$

```
pnorm(38.5, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.05193808
```

For consistency, at this point you could decide
it's OK to have $\alpha$ just a bit above 5% because of the normal approximation.

Then, upon observing $T = 35$ you could reject $H_0$ because $35 \le 38.5$ or you could get
a matching (continuity-corrected) approximate P-value $0.0202 < 0.0519,$ and use that to Reject.

```
pnorm(35.5, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.02015249
```

By contrast, if you feel guilty testing at level
$5.2\%$ instead of $5\%,$ then you could
revise the critical value to $c = 37,$ $\alpha = 0.0385,$ and the P-value for observed $T = 35$ to
$0.0202.$ Then Reject because of the small
observed value of $T$ or its small P-value.

```
pnorm(37.5, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.03854994
pnorm(35.5, 50, sqrt(50))
[1] 0.02015249
```

It is important to choose a method and to be
consistent in its application throughout.

Unfortunately, many tests pretend that it is possible to
have level *exactly* 5% when using the normal
approximation. Also, normal approximation for
Poisson tests is usually reserved for hyp0thetical
values of $\lambda$ that are large enough that
normal approximations are OK without continuity
correction.

Almost all statistical software programs ignore
critical values and report P-values. Some use normal approximations (with or without notice in the output), sometimes with continuity corrections (with or without notice).

Comment: Bruce, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I'm able to connect it with my question. Therefore, I've edited it. When I wrote critical region condition, I meant the condition with $ z<q_{\alpha}$, which with the correction seems to lead to a paradox.

Comment: My last displayed equation is essentially copied from your last displayed equation, with very minor differences in notation. I'm sure your can make the connection by comparing the two. // I guess part of the message is that I think it's both more difficult and less accurate to use normal aprx than to do the exact test form the Poisson distribution using R.

Comment: Bruce, I think I understand all your computations and agree with them... However, what I wanted to know was how to deal with the problematic condition $z_0 < q_{\alpha}$ which results from my computations, whether we use a correction or not. I say it's problematic because, when using a normal approximation,  for 2 different p-values (with or without correction) we have the same condition $z_0 < q_{\alpha}$...

Comment: Please try your formulas with actual _numbers_ to see that continuity cor. plays a role for both critical value and P-value. You never explicitly define $Z_0$ or $q_\alpha.$ Without cont. cor. you will Rej if test statistic is below critical value or if P-value is below $\alpha.$ Same is true with continuity correction. // And once more, the need to fuss with continuity corrections occurs only because you're using slightly inaccurate normal approximations. Different texts have various conventions re. cont. corr. // We're about to get busted for chatting in Comments, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Bruce, hello again. Thanks for your patience. I must disagree with you on the issue that almost all programmes when doing test will show both the p-value **and** the test statistic. Hence, my original question. I've edited the question to reflect that. I hope I haven't put you off.